# Linear algebraic methods for block factorization for matrix representation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory, numerical-linear-algebra

Let us assume I have a [matrix representation for an algebraic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation).

Do there exist linear algebraic algorithms to simultaneous block factorization like this:

$$\bf M_i = SC_iS^{-1}$$

Where $\bf M_i$ is representation matrix for element $i$ and so the $\bf C_i$ correspond to group operation on element $i$ in irreducible representation (maximally "squeezed" diagonal block-matrices)?

Comment: By block-factorization, do you mean a block-diagonalization along the lines of [Maschke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem)? Are we necessarily talking about finite groups?  If so, then you might find [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_finite_groups) useful.  I would also recommend chapters 18-19 of Dummit and Foote if you're looking for a reference

Comment: If you are talking about finite groups, we could find the $C_i$ pretty easily using [character tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_table), but finding $S$ is a bit trickier.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yep, I think it is what I mean. There is a chance I don't know enough abstract algebra yet to know precisely what I mean.

Comment: Let's keep it simple: what do we know about the algebraic group?  Is it necessarily finite?

Comment: An example worth keeping in mind: the representation of $(\Bbb Z,+)$ given by 
$$
n \mapsto \pmatrix{1&n\\0&1}
$$
is reducible, but cannot be written as a direct sum (i.e. a diagonal sum) of representations of $\Bbb Z$. If we're working over finite fields, we sometimes run into trouble with finite groups.

Comment: 2x2 block would be smallest block then. If we imagine we had group $(\mathbb Z^2,+)$ taking us on some lattice in plane, I would be OK with finding a 4x4 matrix with two such 2x2 blocks on diagonal.

Comment: All right.  In the terminology of representation theory, you're looking for a way to break representations into a sum of [indecomposable representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation#Decomposable_and_Indecomposable_representations).  As for the algorithm, it really depends on what we know about the group.  As I've said, there's one approach that works for finite groups.  An entirely different approach would be required for [semisimple Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group#Semisimple_and_reductive_groups)